# MSE to predict Values 0 and 1

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am building a deep neural network to predict values 0 and 1 .My training data contains class labels 0 and 1 .Currently i am getting a cross validation loss around .25 . How good is the model performing?

Comment: Compare against a baseline of always predicting the majority class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicting $0.5$ for all items in your case would also give you MSE of $0.25$. That is because independently of whether the true label is $0$ or $1$, the squared error for each example will be $0.5^2 = 0.25$

Your model is performing badly under an MSE measure, when such a simple model that does not take input data into account can get the same score.

However, it is debatable whether MSE gives you a useful metric here.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using MSE?  It's not completely impossible but the usual framework is done against the probabilities and usually for forecasts. You can read more about it by researching Brier scores.  However, it doesn't appear you're doing this and instead just minimize against the labels.

You should use a more appropriate measure like cross entropy.

Comment: These need not be considered Labels , rather a Rating , like the MovieLens  Dataset Rating

Comment: Even if it's a rating it may be a label.